# How to use IDE when dropdown select id and names always differ?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm a newbie using IDE

I'm not sure of a way to record drop down menus in one part of a system as the select id & name always differs depending on a particular ref number i.e.

```
command> select 
target >id=selUQZ
value >label=ABC USER
```

whilst the next time it will be different as it is a different request being assigned:

```
command> select 
target >id=selZ58 
value >label=ABC USER
```

It's an 'assigned to' field where I'm assigning requests to different users.

Can anyone help?

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you include some of the <html> for the page you're trying to test I should be able to assist you further. If your `ID`s are dynamic you'll have to change the `Target` field to use another `locator` like `xpath`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be work for you if your `id` first three `id=sel` value never change.`target >//div[contains(@id,'sel')]` is means that will be selected that include `id=sel`

`command> select`

`target >//div[contains(@id,'sel')]`

`value >label=ABC USER`